# Jmeter : Number of active threads

Tags: testing, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, continuous-testing

- I am using jmeter in elemetery freya (14.04)
- I have a jmeter test plan with view results tree
- I am trying to generate a csv file in view results tree including the number of active threads field.
- It appears to me that the detail is being entered in the result.csv file, but the values representing this attribute has no field name, and hence that detail cannot be used in a graph which I want to create from the result.csv
- I have changed JMETER-INSTALL-DIR/bin/jmeter.properties according to https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginInstall/#Configure-JMeter
- How can I get a result.csv file with a suitable fieldname like "active-threads"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't change anything in *jmeter.properties* file, upgrade to new JMeter version will discard your changes. Use *user.properties* file instead
2. The in order to add column names to CSV file add the following property to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
   ```

Assuming good configuration you should be seeing `grpThreads` and `allThreads` columns along with the values.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and ways of working with them

Comment: the values grpThreads and allThreads are already available in the csv file..But there is no such label for active-threads

Comment: `allThreads` == active threads overall. `grpThreads` == active threads for the current thread group

Comment: But for me thats showing just  the total threads.  Let me test it.. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You are right ..all threads was the field I  was looking for.. But can you help me with one more thing.. What can I do to get a plot with curves representing each request i make ? Or, should it be done while parsing the csv file?